# Add unique class to each td in each row jquery/coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to add a unique class (using the row index) to each td in each row. The table rows are dynamically generated by the user, I just need to format the rows on page load. I'm not that good at javascript, so I may be doing this wrong.

Table:

```
    <table class="inventory">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="invoice_th"><span>Item <br /><%= link_to "Create New Item", new_item_path, target: "_blank" %></span></th>
                <th class="invoice_th"><span>Description</span></th>
                <th class="invoice_th"><span>Unit Cost</span></th>
                <th class="invoice_th"><span>Quantity</span></th>
                <th class="invoice_th"><span>Price</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="itablerow">
          <td class="invoice_td"><%= link_to '#', class: "remove_fields cut btn btn-danger" do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                <% end %><span id="item">   
            <%= f.select :name, options_from_collection_for_select(@items, 'name', 'name', f.object.name), {include_blank: "Select Items"}, id: "sel2", class: "select_box" %></span>
          </td>
          <td class="invoice_td"><span id="description"><%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: "Description", class: "form-control" %></span></td>
          <td class="invoice_td"><span id="unit_cost"><%= text_field_tag "unit_cost", f.object.unit_cost, data: {autonumeric: true, aSign: 'USD'}, placeholder: "0.00", class: "form-control" %><%= f.hidden_field :unit_cost, :value => f.object.unit_cost %></span></td>
          <td class="invoice_td"><span id="quantity"><%= f.number_field :quantity, placeholder: "0", class: "form-control" %></span></td>
          <td class="invoice_td"> <%= text_field_tag "total", f.object.total, data: {autonumeric: true, aSign: 'USD'}, placeholder: "0.00", class: "form-control" %><%= f.hidden_field :total %></td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to add a unique class to each td in each row so I can easily grab it later and format the unit cost and the total properly as currency.

Here's the coffeescript I'm using:

```
$(document).ready ->
  prices = []
  $('.inventory > tbody > tr').each ->
    activeRow = $(this).index()
    $('td:nth-child(1) select').addClass 'sel' + activeRow
    $('.sel' + activeRow).select2()
    $('td:nth-child(2) input').addClass 'description_' + activeRow
    $('td:nth-child(3) input:text').addClass 'unit_cost_' + activeRow
    $('td:nth-child(3) input:hidden').addClass 'unit_cost_hidden_' + activeRow
    $('td:nth-child(4) input').addClass 'quantity_' + activeRow
    $('td:nth-child(5) input:text').addClass 'total_' + activeRow
    $('td:nth-child(5) input:hidden').addClass 'total_hidden_' + activeRow
    quantity = $('td:nth-child(4) input').val()
    unit_cost = $('td:nth-child(3) input').val()
    fixedUnitcost = accounting.unformat(unit_cost) / 100
    total = parseInt(fixedUnitcost, 10) * parseInt(quantity, 10)
    $('td:nth-child(3) input:text').val accounting.formatMoney(fixedUnitcost)
    $('td:nth-child(5) input:text').val accounting.formatMoney(total)
    $('td:nth-child(5) input:hidden').val total
    $('td:nth-child(3) input:hidden').val accounting.unformat(unit_cost)
    price = accounting.unformat($(this).find('td:last input').val())
    prices.push price
  sum = prices.reduce(((pv, cv) ->
    pv + cv
    ), 0)
  $('.shown_total').text accounting.formatMoney(sum)
  totalDue = $('.shown_total').text()
  amountPaid = $('.amount_paid').text()
  balanceDue = accounting.unformat(totalDue) - accounting.unformat(amountPaid)
  $('.balance_due').text accounting.formatMoney(balanceDue)
  $('.total').val sum * 100
```

Currently what's happening is it will create the class properly, but then it will add it to all td elements.

For example: After the page loads every "description" td element (the 2nd column in the table) in a table with 3 rows will have a class of: description_0 description_1 description_2

How can I get it so the first row's td's have the classes (and ONLY the classes):
description_0, unit_cost_0, etc.

And the 2nd row's td's have the classes:
description_1, unit_cost_1, etc.

I've been working on this for 2 days and can't find a solution that works. any ideas?

Comment: `What I'm trying to accomplish is to add a unique class to each td in each row` - this is a bad idea, and you don't need it.  If later, you want to iterate the rows and process each TD in them, you can do just that, without having a unique classname per TD.

Comment: Have any idea how I could accomplish the end goal though? Adding a unique class seemed like the best way to target the elements I need to format them, but I'm up for a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Study the example below, adjust as needed and apply.

```js
$('tr:first td').addClass('amount');

$('tr:last td').addClass('discount');

$(function() {

  $('.amount').attr('class', function(i) {
    return 'amount' + (i + 1);
  });

  $('.discount').attr('class', function(i) {
    return 'discount' + (i + 1);
  });

});
```

```css
.amount1,
.amount2,
.amount3,
.discount1,
.discount2,
.discount3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: calibri;
}
.amount1 {
  color: maroon;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.amount2 {
  color: green;
}
.amount3 {
  color: Orange;
}
.discount1 {
  color: black;
}
.discount2 {
  color: gold;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.discount3 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="200" border="1">

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

**again:** This is just an example, study and adjust as needed;